# sweetalert only delete the first colum of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using sweetalert for my delete confirmation but its only delete when i clicked the first column only,if i clicked other colum the sweetalert wont popup,here is my table:

```
          $i=1;
          foreach ($category as $key) { ?>

          <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $i++ ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $key['category_name'] ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $key['category_code'] ?></td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <a class="" href='#' data-role="editCategory" data-id="<?php echo $key['cat_id'] ?>"
                data-cat="<?php echo $key['category_name'] ?>" data-cat_code="<?php echo $key['category_code'] ?>"
                data-toggle="modal" title="Kemaskini"><span class="fe fe-edit fe-20"></span></a>

              | 
              <a class="text-danger" id="delete" href="<?php echo base_url('catalog/del_category/'.$key['cat_id']) ?>" title="Padam"><span class="fe fe-trash fe-20"></span></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

here is my script :

```
$('#delete').on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var url = $(this).attr('href');

 Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
 }).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
   window.location.replace(url);
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Hi , because you are using same id for all i.e :`id="delete"` instead use class and then change `$('#delete')` to `$('.delete')` .

Comment: Hi, use class selector instead of id.

Comment: i tried with class,then the url `undefined`

Comment: you need to add that class here `class="text-danger delete"`  .

Comment: oh my bad,i added it to the ` <span class="">`,thanks for the solutions

Answer (score 0):

You should change the selector from `$('#delete')` to `$('.delete')` in the JavaScript
and change all the button in html from `id='delete'` to `class='delete'`